# How to store (and load) a zsh String array to a file?

Tags: zsh, array

I want to store an array of some quotes (so basically real-world strings with new lines) in a file. How can I achieve it? I thought of setting the IFS to something like “xxxxxxxxx74765xxx” (which will never occur in my strings), but of course, IFS only works for single chars.

I can think of some ugly hacks to do it (e.g., store that nonsense string as a line between elements, read the file line by line and check each line against it, and rebuild the array thus.), but I will appreciate some more experienced opinions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do:

```
typeset array > file
```

To load:

```
source file
```

(you can also use `typeset -p array` to also save the attributes of the array variable (exported, unique...)).

Alternatively:

```
print -rl -- ${(qq)array} > file
```

To load:

```
eval "array=($(<file))"
```

For your *separator* idea:

```
print -r -- ${(j[separator])array} > file
```

To load:

```
array=("${(@s[separator])"$(<file)"}")
```

(though beware it removes all trailing newline characters from the last element of the array and it doesn't work for an empty array).

Answer (score 2):

The two **portable** (ksh, zsh, bash) solutions AFAICT are:

```
 typeset -p arr >./file              # save array
 . ./file                            # read array
```

And

```
printf '%q\n' "${arr[@]}" >./file    # save array
eval "arr=( $(< ./file) )"           # read array
```

Note that the first solution will create a **local** variable if used inside a function in bash.